# Eсли vs. в случае если

Tags: семантика

Скажите, пожалуйста, для носителя русского языка есть семантическая разница, когда Вы слышите:

> 1. **Если** я не вернусь в полночь, звони в полицию.
> 2. **В случае если** я не вернусь в полночь, звони в полицию.

Или "если" и "в случае если" абсолютные синонимы для Вас?

Answer (score 1):

Синонимы-то они синонимы, но "в случае если" казёнщиной попахивает... Пожалуй, этот "случай" будет уместен в какой-нибудь памятке-инструктаже, где перечисляются именно случаи:

*В случае если на вас обрушился потолок, звоните девять-один-один;
в случае если вы пьяным сбили пешехода, немедленно бегите к лотку с мороженым и заедайте алкоголь...*

Comment: На мой взгляд, не только в документах. Зависит еще от того, насколько вероятен "случай". Сравните: "Сегодня вечером я объявлю кредиторам, что я банкрот. В случае, если не вернусь в полночь, звони в полицию." - "Пойду прогуляюсь по ночному городу. Если не вернусь в полночь, звони в полицию."

Comment: @Galina Avanesova: спасибо за ответ! признаю я всегда трудно понимаю стиль, на котором Вы говорите/пишете. не поняла в Вашем первом предложении - это синонимы или нет; let alone то что стоит после запятой... тем не менее спасибо! : )

Comment: Анонимушка, я говорю и пишу на русском разговорном - это полезнее для иностранки, чем нейтральный стиль. Я сказала после запятой, что они а) синонимы, б) есть небольшое стилистическое отличие ("в случае если" - более протокольно, казённо).

Comment: *я говорю и пишу на русском разговорном* - не выдумывайте, вы в приступе панибратства переходите на слащавый и малопонятный диалекте. *это полезнее для иностранки* - А это-то кто вам сказал?!

Comment: @Anonym *признаю я всегда трудно понимаю стиль, на котором Вы говорите/пишете* - не только вы Галину "трудно понимаете".

Answer (score 1):

**Если я не вернусь в полночь, звони в полицию** (нейтральный союз ЕСЛИ).

**В случае если я не вернусь в полночь, звони в полицию** (союз В СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ имеет дополнительное значение:  выражение неопределенности ситуации).

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ**

Сложный предлог В СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ имеет определенную коннотацию (дополнительное значение) , что сказывается на его стилевой характеристике. Он как бы выражает **спектр различных обстоятельств, которые могут повлиять на дальнейшее течение событий.** Именно поэтому союз В СЛУЧАЕ ЕСЛИ так часто используется **в деловой речи**, где все эти варианты рассматриваются.

**Но и в художественных текстах он иногда применяется**, например: Мои наилучшие пожелания тебе **в случае, если** ты скоро вернёшься домой, **в противном случае** я желаю тебе мужества, много мужества, чтобы выдержать тюремные страдания. [Даниил Гранин. Зубр (1987)]

Из словаря:  **СЛУЧАЙ**. 1. То, что случилось, произошло; **непредвиденное событие, происшествие**;  2. (с опр. и предлогами: в, при, на). **Положение дел, вещей, обстоятельств.** При удобном случае.  В лучшем случае (при самых благоприятных обстоятельствах). В таком случае (при данных обстоятельствах, условиях, тогда).

Comment: Спасибо! : ) сейчас буду думать можно провести ли параллель к английским союзам if & in case

Answer (score 0):

Anonym, семантической разницы тут нету. Во всяком случае явно на неё никто не указал. Второй вариант (В случае если я не вернусь в полночь, звони в полицию) для разговорной речи совершенно не характерен.

Более того, мне попадались утверждения, что "в случае, если" является избыточным и так называемым "канцеляризмом", то есть излишне формальным, мертвым языком бюрократов (на русском это слово имеет негативную коннотацию).

Это все не лишено оснований. Однако я считаю, что при необходимости перечислить большое количество подобных "случаев", оно вполне может пригодиться.

Например, объяснить распределение мест в каком-то (условном) футбольном чемпионате удобно так:

===
/ 1 Команды распределяются по местам в соответствии с количеством набранных очков.

/ 2 В случае, если две команды, претендуещие на первое место имют поровну очков, то назначается дополнительный матч за первое место.

/ 3 В случае, если три или более команды набирают поровну очков, то преимущество получает команда, набравшая большее количество очков в матчах между этими командами

/ 4 в случае, если две или более команды из числа набравших поровну очков набрали поровну очков в матчах между собой, то преимущество получает та команда, которая в матчах между этими командами имеет лучшую разницу забитых и пропущенных мячей... [1]

/ - и так далее до бесконечности можно аккуратно расписать все подробности положения о чемпионате. Здесь "в случае" дает информацию о начале смыслового блока, в то время как обычное "если" может встретиться и в его середине.
Без "случая" здесь не все будет так наглядно.

===
И это действительно почти полная ангалогия с английскими if и in case if.
но в обычном предложении типа "Если будет дождь, поездка не состоится" случай совершенно излишне. Тут аналогии с английским нет.

С другой стороны, в русском есть конструкция, не слишком часто употрбляемая, но полезная, "на случай": ***"на [тот] случай, если"*** (сравните: на всякий случай"). Например: *"На случай, если не будет возможности сообщить свое местонахождение, возьмите запасную рацию"*. Вот она-то, эта конструкция, не может быть заменена простым "если", её значение близко к английскому "for" в оборотах типа "for an accident". Так что некоторая тонкость в семантике тут есть.

Да, с Sibylla я не совсем согласен. Нет тут тех оттенков смысла, которые она видит, я вижу другие, те о которых написал.

[1]: *(Для желающих отредактировать: пожалуйста, **не делайте тут список***, он не нужен и плохо смотрится)*